# simple local repository manager tool for maven

Tags: maven, repository

I am using maven to build java projects. I find difficulty in managing artifacts of maven local repository. so, i need a simple tool for managing local repositories of maven.
I seen the **apache-archiva** and **nexus** , but those and big tools.
I also searched the internet but i seen only central repository manager tool. I can't find a tool for managing local repository.
I need to know about the artifacts in my local maven reporitory. I don't want to check each folder of my local repository to see what artifacts are installed.

so, please someone tell me about the tools to manage maven local repository.

Comment: What kind of exact problem do you have with your local cache? Why do you need to look if some artifact is installed? Are you within a company? If you build needed dependencies will be downloaded? If not there which are needed and do not exist fail the build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no tools to manage the local repository.

The local repository is more or less just a cache.

Inside a company, you usually set up a Nexus or Artifactory server to manage external and internal artifacts.

Comment: Those are big in size i need a small tool

Comment: What exactly do you need to find out about your local repository?

Comment: most of time i work in offline. i download libraries in jar files and add it to local repository. Thus, i want to know about artifacts in local maven repository

Comment: So you want to know whether some artifact you specify is in the local repository?

Comment: yes, and i want to know what version is already installed so i use the installed version (i already said i work in offline enviroinment most of time). And i don't want to manually check each artifact by searching folders

Comment: I guess the only advice I can give you is to set up a Nexus or Artifactory server. If you need a search function for the local repository, you probably have to program it yourself.